# How can i fix the error i get when i run cordova build android on windows cmd

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile

When Ever i run the cordova build android command i keep getting these errors and i dont know how to fix it, i have tried to google buh nothing helped.

i am already in the cordova directory: i run
`cordova emulate or build android`
i get the following errors:

`FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.`

`* Where:`

`Script 'C:\Users\ededd\Desktop\bookExchangeApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\cordova.gradle' line: 75`

`* What went wrong:`

`A problem occurred evaluating script.`

`> No usable Android build tools found. Highest 33.x installed version is 33.0.1; Recommended version is 33.0.2.`

`* Try:`

`> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.`

`> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.`

`> Run with --scan to get full insights.`

`* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org`

`Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.`

`You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.`

`See https://docs.gradle.org/7.6/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings`

`BUILD FAILED in 9s`

`Command failed with exit code 1: C:\Users\ededd\Desktop\bookExchangeApp\platforms\android\gradlew -b C:\Users\ededd\Desktop\bookExchangeApp\platforms\android\build.gradle cdvBuildDebug`

`C:\Users\ededd\Desktop\bookExchangeApp\www>`

Answer (score 0):

Just update your build tools from 33.0.1 to 33.0.2. in Android Studio / SDK Manager

Comment: i have tried this, on windows , or maybe am doing it wrong...still not working